# Render SASS files correctly in File.read (inside PDF file)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, sass

I generate a pdf and have to include css in the generated file so that the styling is correct in the pdf.  To do this I have

```
<%= File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets", "application.css.scss")) %>
<%= File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets", "app.css.scss")) %>
```

But the sass isn't templated correctly.  Does anyone know what the correct code to render the files right are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace File.read with

```
YourApp::Application.assets["application.css.scss"].to_s.html_safe
```

where YourApp is the name of the application you are working on. This will cause rails to render the scss inline.